# Unknown field in BigQuery table error when using Cloud DLP

Tags: google-cloud-dlp

I am using a script to programmatically call the Cloud **DLP** API to inspect tables in BigQuery.  The script runs fine mostly, but I get the error below once in awhile.
I tried to search but there is no content on this problem.

```
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Unknown field in BigQuery table: `finding_id`
```

It seems to be an ephemeral problem, if I re-run my script there won't be the error anymore, and it appears randomly for tables.

The `finding_id` field in question is not a field in my tables.
Seems like it might be a field used by Cloud **DLP** API when it writes Inspection results to BigQuery.

**UPDATE:**
This is the API I am calling (using Python library):

```
dlp = google.cloud.dlp_v2.DlpServiceClient()
operation = dlp.create_dlp_job(
    request={
        "parent": parent,
        "inspect_job": inspect_job
    }
)
```

Comment: What's the API method you called when this happened? What's in the request body?

Comment: I think this might be a bug, looking into it. Will need to verify which precise api methods you are calling.

Comment: @JordannaChord I have added the details to the question

Comment: I'm assuming you were storing findings and had actions on too? If so, we have found the culprit and am working on a solution.

Comment: Hi, I opened a [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com/174128658) on your behalf for better tracking. Feel free to star it.

Comment: @JordannaChord yes, they were jobs to inspect BigQuery tables in one project and record the findings in another project in BigQuery tables

Comment: The issue should be resolved.